# Efficient way to find a record based on many columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I need to identify a record without its ID in a large table (100M rows) that contains over 30 columns of data and associations.

Through testing, we've determined that we have to search 15 columns together to reliably find the right record.

Building an index on 15 columns produces a massive index ~50% as big as the original table. Without an index, the following search is of course extremely slow:

```
Company.find_or_initialize_by(field1: h[:field1], field2: h[:field2], ...]
```

This is my current intended path:

1. Identify the most effective ~3 fields at narrowing down the number of records.
2. `add_index :companies, [:field1, :field2, :field3]`
3. Then do something like...

   ````
   companies = Company.where("field1 = ? AND field2 = ? AND field3 = ?", h[:field1], h[:field2], h[:field3])

   # At this point we expect `companies` to have fewer than 20 records in 99.9% of cases.
   company = companies.select{ |c| ...remaining 12 attributes... } # No DB query
   company ||= Company.new(...)```
   ````

**Would something like this make sense, or is there technically a better way?**

Comment: "Building an index on 15 columns produces a massive index ~50% as big as the original table."  So what?  Sometimes getting the job done takes extra space.  Is this too much space by some objective measure, or are you just inventing things to worry about?

Comment: Building an index on 3 fields is fine, but then put all the conditions in the WHERE clause and PostgreSQL will match them up to the available indexes itself, and filter on the ones not already satisfied by the chosen index(es).  There is no reason to apply them yourself later, it just makes things more complicated and error-prone.

Comment: @jjanes To your question about space, the original index is large enough that it has a meaningful impact on backup/restore times and hosting costs.

Comment: Every thing is a trade off, in your case you would be trading space for performance.  How much additional performance do you need? Perhaps placing  an index a few most common columns would give sufficient performance gain without excessive space requirement.  So **is there technically a better way**; unfortunately, No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that creating an index with all 15 columns is unfeasible (based on the comments of the question), I would probably approach this problem in a way that preserves a good memory-performance balance.

I would start looking for a reduced set of columns that, when combined, provide enough entropy. For example, given a table with columns A-Z, If filtering by columns B, H and J reduces the result set to 0,01% of its original value, it's already a good start.

Then, I would create an index with these columns, and would analyse the [query plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html) to make sure Postgres is actually using that index. Most likely, Postgres will follow two steps:

1. Use the index to read from disk the rows matching columns B, H and J
2. Once these records are loaded into the memory, evaluate the remaining conditions to discard the ones that don't match the remaining conditions in the query.

Choosing the right combination of columns for the index will vary depending on the distribution of data stored and the memory-performance balance that you want to achieve.